# How to update state with each change on text field flutter

Tags: flutter, algolia

I am building a search bar which brings some resuts from algolia. everything is working fine, except that the results listview view doesn't show the new resuts until I close the keyboard. but I need to update automatically with every new letter I write in the text field (while the keyboard is opened), same like auto complete function. what is mimssing here?
(note that all of this is inside a buttomsheet)

I also tried to replace the controller listner with onChange (){}, same issue is there.
the list view doesn't rebuild untill I close the keyboard.

The Funcion and the listner Code:

```
class _CategoriesPageState extends State<CategoriesPage> {
String _searchTerm = "";
List<AlgoliaObjectSnapshot> _results = [];
bool _searching = false;
TextEditingController _searchText = TextEditingController(text: "");

_search() async {
setState(() {
  _searching = true;
});

Algolia algolia = const Algolia.init(
  applicationId: 'XP6QXPHMDJ',
  apiKey: '283351eb9d0a111a8fb4f2fdb7b8450a',
);

AlgoliaQuery query = algolia.instance.index('BusinessProfilesCollection');
query = query.query(_searchText.text);

_results = (await query.getObjects()).hits;

setState(() {
  _searching = false;
});
}

@override
void initState() {
_searchText.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    _search();
  });
});
super.initState();
}
```

the Text Field Code:

```
 TextField(
                                  controller: _searchText,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    color: Colors.grey[850],
                                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: 'Search ...',
                                    hintStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  )),
```

The Results Widget:

```
 Container(
                          height: 300.h,
                          child: _searching == true
                              ? Center(
                                  child: Text("Searching, please wait..."),
                                )
                              : _results.length == 0
                                  ? Center(
                                      child: Text("No results found."),
                                    )
                                  : ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: _results.length,
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext ctx, int index) {return ...}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bottom sheet doesnt update state by default. Wrap the content of the bottom sheet with a statefulbuilder

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState /*You can rename this!*/) {
        return Container(
          child: TextField(onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              //This will rebuild the bottom sheet
            });
          }),
        );
      });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this is the problem. I tried this in a different page rather than the buttomsheet and it worked perfectly. Will test your solution and feedback

Comment: Worked! ..  thanks a lot, I had to put await on executing the search function so it completes the results before restating the sheet. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
                   TextField(
                         onChanged: (value) {
                             setState(() {
                                   //This will refresh the page
                                  });
                                },
                                  controller: _searchText,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                    color: Colors.grey[850],
                                    fontSize: 14.sp,
                                  ),
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: 'Search ...',
                                    hintStyle:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                              ),
```

Comment: This wasn't working because I am using bottomsheet, the previous comment gave me the best way forward. thanks Krishnan